# In Azure can I dynamically checkout a repo when using multi-repo triggers?

Tags: git, repository, azure-pipelines, pipeline, git-checkout

I am using Azure git, and my Pipeline is using multi-repo triggers.

I want to checkout the repo that triggered the build. I see that `checkout: self` uses the repository where the .yml file lives, not the one that triggered the build.

I found that `$(Build.Repository.Name)` holds the name of the repo that triggered the build.

So in my .yml file, I tried to pass it to the `checkout` step but got an error:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: A
    type: git
    name: Dev/A
    trigger:
    - '*'

  - repository: B
    type: git
    name: Dev/B
    trigger:
    - '*'

  - repository: C
    type: git
    name: Dev/C
    trigger:
    - '*'

pool: Default

steps:
- checkout: git://Dev/$(Build.Repository.Name)@refs/heads/master
- checkout: git://Dev/B@refs/heads/master
```

The error message is:

```
The pipeline is not valid. The repository $(Build.Repository.Name) in project Dev could not be retrieved. Verify the name and credentials being used.
```

How can I pass the variable to the checkout step?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: No, we just avoid using multi-repo triggers now.

Answer (score 0):

The pre-defined variable `Build.Repository.Name` is the name of the triggering repository not the name of the repo that triggered the build. See: [Build variables (DevOps Services)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) for details.

In addition, by reference to this doc: [Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops), the `checkout` step is validated when queuing this build, I am afraid that you cannot change its reference repository name using [runtime variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script), which can set different values to scripts and tasks at runtime.

Therefore, as a workaround that you could use the pre-defined variable `Build.TriggeredBy.ProjectID` to get **ID of the project** that contains the triggering build. And using `uild.TriggeredBy.DefinitionId` to get the **DefinitionID** of the triggering build.

After that using this Rest API: [Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) to get the repository that triggered the build in repository.url from the response. Its format will be like `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/{repository name}`.

Finally, you could add a [Command Line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to checkout this repository using command `git clone https://username:PAT@dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/{repository name}`, you could generate a [PAT with full access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page).

Comment: Hi twasbrillig, Does my answer help? If yes, you could Accept it as an Answer, it could help other community members who get the same issues, appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Is there any other options than use git clone? It seems awkward because it quite common case to have, for example, single build pipe with artifacts and single release pipe for deploying artifacts into 'this and that' environments like Test1 and Test2 environments where we just pick one we need at queue time. After that we expect to drag linked build source and do, for example, database migration specific to our environment. Problem is checkout task that can not work with runtime variables, it uses only queue time variables. I don't see limits for using runtime vars.